# Creating pull request using cURL in TFS 2017 (on-premise)

Tags: rest, curl, tfs

i have been following the microsoft document on tfs 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics

So, i am trying to create a `pull request` via the terminal using the below command.

```
curl -X POST -k -u myUser:<Personal_Access_Token> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"sourceRefName": "refs/heads/fte", "targetRefName": "refs/heads/dev", "title": "test api", "description": "another test for pr with rest api", "reviewers": [ { "id":  { null } } ] }' https://<installname>/<Projects>/_apis/git/repositories/<git_repository>/pullRequests?api-version=3.0-preview
```

But nothing comes back from the server

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:00 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300453 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I can though, perform `GET` resquest on the TFS server using `curl` command (for things like: list the projects/repositories etc). but the `POST` doesn't seem to be working.

note: i am not sure where i can find the `reviewer` id (guid) in tfs, so i assigned it as `null`.  i hope that is not causing the issue here.

Any suggestion/solution is appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: i mentioned "I can though, perform GET resquest on the TFS server using curl command (for things like: list the projects/repositories etc). but the POST doesn't seem to be working." ... Looking into my terminal history, i was using the right endpoint for the GET unlike in POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part with the https endpoint. i was specifying the port 8080 while i was trying to use the `https`.. So the malformed endpoint looked like

```
https://somename.com:8080/blah
```

i changed it to

```
https://somename.com/blah
```

and it worked